# difference between presentModalView and addSubview?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

When revealing a new view, what are the differences between these two and when would you use each?

Also, what's the right way to nest views. for example, I have a UIImageview that animates onto my view and it has a button on it. I want to put that image and the button in their own view, then simply animate the view and have both handled simultaneously.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question :

presentModalView is you show another viewcontroller (called modalViewController) to get some data, temporary view... (more about [ModalViewController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW1) here) . Generally, it is another view and can hide your original view

addSubview: you add another view in your current screen, you don't show another view. Which means you are still in your current viewController.

For the second question:
I will go for presentModalViewController here. You can create another UIViewController contains a UIImageView and 2 buttons then you can just present it